# How to get rxjs throttle with Subject to work properly?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have a stream of data that never stops. An algorithm needs to be run on the individual items of the data stream. The algorithm cannot keep up with the data stream so the data items arriving while the algorithm is processing will need to be dropped. I am attempting to use `rxjs`'s `throttle` operator to accomplish this, but the throttle does not get reset when I emit from my `Subject` that I am using as the [durationSelector](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/throttle). However, the throttle does work when I replace my `Subject` with the `interval` operator. I am guessing I am missing something simple, but I'm not seeing it.

```
import { Subject, interval, range } from 'rxjs';
import { throttle } from 'rxjs/operators';

function algorithm() {
  // simulate algorithm taking 1000ms
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
}
const dataStream = interval(200);
const algorithmDone = new Subject();
const pipeline = dataStream.pipe(throttle(sv => algorithmDone));
pipeline.subscribe(x => {
  console.log('here ' + x);
  algorithm();
  algorithmDone.next(0);
});
```

Runnable code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-tbs8qz

The above has a data stream producing data every 200ms. The algorithm takes 1000ms so approximately every fifth item from `dataStream` should be printed. I only get the first number with the above implementation. If I replace `algorithmDone` in `throttle()` with `interval(1000)`, I get the expected output. Why doesn't this work with my `Subject`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `algorithm()` function returns a promise yet you are using it as if it were synchronous.

**Change:**

```
pipeline.subscribe(x => {
  console.log('here ' + x);
  algorithm();
  algorithmDone.next(0);
});
```

**To Either:**

```
pipeline.subscribe(x => {
  console.log('here ' + x);
  algorithm().then(() => algorithmDone.next(0));
});
```

**or:**

```
pipeline.subscribe(async x => {
  console.log('here ' + x);
  await algorithm();
  algorithmDone.next(0);
});
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple. Thanks!